# Does Wild Shape count as a spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, wild-shape

I just started playing a druid, hit level 2 and chose Circle of the Moon. This gives me the ability to use Wild Shape as a bonus action. A situation came up where I wanted to cast a spell, and then use my bonus action to transform. I was stopped saying you can't cast 2 spells in the same turn.

Is Wild Shape considered a spell and fall under this rule?

Comment: Were you "stopped" by the DM? Who told you this?

Comment: I was stopped by a couple of the other players and DM wasnt sure about it so we just went with the assumption it was a spell until we could find the answer. Thanks all who responded.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

### No

A class feature might give you a spell, but it explicitly says so in this case. See Barbarian's Path of the Totem Warrior for example:

> At 3rd level when you adopt this path, you gain the ability to cast the *beast sense* and *speak with animals* spells.

A *spell* is a special term in 5e, a spell description always says its casting time, components, duration and range. For instance, only spells which duration is not Instantaneous can be dispelled.

The Wild Shape only says you assume the shape of a beast, not cast a spell:

> Starting at 2nd level, you can use your action to magically assume the shape of a beast that you have seen before

That means it doesn't consume your spell slots, can't be counterspelled, and you can use it with your bonus actions on the same turn you cast a spell (providing your circle is the Circle of the Moon, otherwise you have to spend Action instead). It is still counts as a magical effect though, hence, wouldn't work in an antimagic field.

Answer (score 17):

## No, Wildshape is not a spell.

A question pertaining to Dispel Magic was asked to Jeremy Crawford, lead rules designer of 5e. They asked if Dispel Magic could target Wild Shape. He said:

> Dispel magic ends spells. Wild Shape isn't a spell.

[source](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/692448278160502786?)

Answer (score 6):

**No, Wild Shape is a magical ability and not a spell.**

As a magical ability, it is affected by an antimagic field such as the one emitted by a beholder but it is not subject to the effect of [*counterspell*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/counterspell).