# Can you use Counterspell/Dispel Magic to prevent a druid from using Wild Shape?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, druid, wild-shape, counterspelling

Is it possible to use [*counterspell*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/counterspell) or [*dispel magic*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/dispel-magic) to prevent a druid from using [Wild Shape](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/druid#WildShape) or forcibly revert them to their original form?

Comment: Related on [What happens when you target a magical effect with dispel magic](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/47717/what-happens-when-you-target-a-magical-effect-with-dispel-magic). Not a dupe because this question also asks about *counterspell.*

Answer (score 12):

## It does not work

Counterspell and Dispel Magic work only on spells, but Wild Shape is [not a spell](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/129469/9552).

Dispel Magic:

> Choose one creature, object, or magical effect within range. Any **spell** of 3rd level or lower on the target ends.

Jeremy Crawford [agrees](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2016/03/02/can-dispel-magic-undo-a-druids-wild-shape/).

Comment: This is correct but could be made better by adding supporting evidence that wild shape is more a spell.  Preemptive +1.

Comment: @NickBrown, Wild Shape is obviously not a spell. [More supporting evidence](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2016/03/02/can-dispel-magic-undo-a-druids-wild-shape/)

Comment: But is it a magical effect?

Comment: @TigerDM That isn't specified any more than action surge is specified as a "magical effect"

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Wild Shape is described as magical.

Comment: @Bloodcinder So are dragons, but their breath can't be dispelled

Comment: @Bloodcinder Dispel Magic works on spells, not magical effects.

Comment: I know that, clearly (see my answer). Korvin, you seemed to be suggesting that Wild Shape isn't magical "any more than action surge is," so I didn't understand the point of your comment (because Wild Shape is in fact specified as magical but Action Surge isn't).

Comment: @TigerDM  [I would argue that Wild Shape is a magical ability, the transformation is magical, but the shape is not.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/178157/23547)

Comment: @KorvinStarmast [I would argue that Wild Shape is a magical ability, the transformation is magical, but the shape is not.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/178157/23547)

Comment: @Bloodcinder [I would argue that Wild Shape is a magical ability, the transformation is magical, but the shape is not.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/178157/23547)

Answer (score 8):

## No.

Here's the relevant rules for [*counterspell*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/counterspell) (emphasis mine):

> You attempt to interrupt a creature in the process of **casting a spell**. If the creature is casting a spell of 3rd level or lower, its **spell fails** and has no effect.

And for [*dispel magic*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/dispel-magic) (emphasis still mine):

> Choose one creature, object, or magical effect within range. Any **spell** of 3rd level or lower on the target **ends**.

Neither of the spells above can affect Wild Shape because it is not a spell. This is because something is only a spell if it's called a spell (see [this related question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/131495/what-counts-as-a-spell) for why), and the rules for Wild Shape don't call it a spell. It doesn't matter that Wild Shape is magical in nature; it is simply not a spell. This is addressed in the [Sage Advice Compendium](https://media.wizards.com/2019/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf), the official source of rules clarifications (bracketed context mine):

> **Can you use *dispel magic* to dispel a magical effect like a vampire's Charm ability or a druid's Wild Shape?** *Dispel magic* has a particular purpose: to break other spells. It has no effect on a vampire's Charm ability or any other magical effect [such as Wild Shape] that isn’t a spell.

If you want to cause non-spell magical effects to end, take a look at the [*antimagic field*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/antimagic-field) spell. With just a breezy 8th-level casting, it can suppress *all* magical effects (except those created by artifacts or deities) including non-spell effects such as Wild Shape. The effect of Wild Shape would be suspended while the druid is within the field. The exact meaning of this suspension is somewhat left to the DM, but probably the druid would revert to their normal form while within the field, then regain their beast form as soon as they exit the field, using the respective hit points of whichever form they are in.