# How can I increase the range of a Dragonborn's breath weapon?

Tags: dnd-5e, racial-traits, area-of-effect, dragonborn, breath-weapon

Is it possible to increase the range/area of a Dragonborn's breath weapon?

If yes, how?

Comment: Instead of asking all feats [one-by-one](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/135011/9552)

Comment: it is better to be very specific than very broad. Once some source material on dragonborns' abilities is released, your question loses value, and the ones that asked feat-by-feat do not. I am voting to close as too broad but won't vote up or down.

Comment: What are your limitations? WotC-only? 3pp? GM fiat?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Currently, not possible

While it is difficult to prove a negative, the Dragonborn's Breath Weapon isn't a magical effect, so does not benefit from any feats that affect magic.

There are feats that affect Dragonborn specifically, but the only one that relates to breath weapons simply allows you to expend your Breath Weapon's use to create a fear effect.