# Can extended spell be used on the druid's wild shape to make it last longer?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, druid, wild-shape, metamagic

A player has a druid with the metamagic adept feat and wondered if he could use the extended spell on his "wild shape" class feature.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### No. Wild Shape doesn't count as a spell, and thus it is not a valid target.

The class feature Wild Shape doesn't count as a spell, see [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/129467/does-wild-shape-count-as-a-spell) and thus is not a valid target for [Extended Spell](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/classes#ExtendedSpell) which requires you to cast a spell:

> When you cast a spell [..]

Answer (score 0):

No, that’s only for spells, and Wild Shape is not a spell.

What I have done in my world, is to let the druid stay in Wild Shape longer if he picks “weaker” forms.

So, for example, suppose we have a 6th level Moon Druid, who can take the form of a CR2 beast for 3 hours. Multiply those two numbers, and you get 6.

In my world, he could choose to be:
a CR2 beast for 3 hours, such as a cave bear or a sabertooth cat, or
a CR1 beast for 6 hours, such as a brown bear or dire wolf, or
a CR1/2 beast for 12 hours, such as a black bear or warhorse, or
a CR1/4 beast for 24 hours, such as a riding horse or a giant badger, or
a CR1/8 beast for 48 hours, such as a mastiff or a mule, or
a CR0 beast forever, such as a housecat or rat.

As long as the two numbers multiply to less than 6 (for this example).